# iMac Summer 2001 G3 CRT Issue

Tags: display, imac

I have an iMac G3 from the Summer of 2001, and it appears to have an issue with its CRT.

After a few minutes of being on, the entire CRT appears to take a yellowish tint which is extremely visible, especially on blue and white colours.

I decided to go into display settings and colour calibration and turn down each RGB channel individually, and I found turning the blue channel down fully reproduces this yellow tint, and I therefore assume the blue gun is not firing fully or at all in some cases. Is there any way this can be fixed and any reason this may occur? I really do not want to replace this machine as it was a Christmas gift as my family knows I collect these older machines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt it's the gun that's the issue, but without getting actual hands-on, it's impossible to tell for sure.

It could be something as simple as color being out of sync and a simple degauss should correct.  Pass a magnet across the front of the screen; that should clear things up.  You don't need anything powerful.  I've used re-purposed speaker magnets back in the day.  I have also seen people use [tool magnetizers](http://radnex.us/tool-magnetizer) with the added benefit that if it doesn't work, you still have a functional tool for future magnetizing needs (from $2 to $10 USD).

If the degauss fails, it may be a component or a faulty solder joint that controls the color hue/saturation.  At this point, it would be best to take it to a pro who specializes in this type of diagnostic/repair.    It's not a difficult repair and shouldn't be costly at all.  It's just that you will be working with extremely high voltages and can be quite dangerous for the novice.

Comment: I guess if it can be flickery at times there is no point in attempting a degauss and its more likely to be a solder or component issue?

Comment: That sounds like a capacitor, but again, until someone actually physically diagnoses it, it's just an educated guess.